# How to wrap XML array-type nodes with parent node

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am working with a org.w3c.dom.Document in Java but it appears that the arrays I'm working with are formatted unexpectedly when I Transform this to an XML document. I believe the problem is that I need a parent Node which contains the array elements.

As an example, I currently have the following XML as output when I transform the Document to a String using a javax.xml.transform.Transformer:

```
<parentNode>
    <childNodes>
        <grandChildNodes>
            <object>
                <foo/>
            </object>
            <object>
                <foo/>
            </object>
        </grandChildNodes>
        <someAdditionalNode/>
    </childNodes>
    <childNodes>
        <grandChildNodes>
            <foo/>
        </grandChildNodes>
        <grandChildNodes>
            <foo/>
        </grandChildNodes>
        <someAdditionalNode/>
    </childNodes>
    <someOtherNode/>
</parentNode>
```

I would like to "wrap" each array with a parent node so the following should be the end result:

```
<parentNode>
    <childNodes>
        <object>
            <grandChildNodes>
                <object>
                    <foo/>
                </object>
                <object>
                    <foo/>
                </object>
            </grandChildNodes>
            <someAdditionalNode/>
        </object>
        <object>
            <grandChildNodes>
                <object>
                    <foo/>
                </object>
                <object>
                    <foo/>
                </object>
            </grandChildNodes>
            <someAdditionalNode/>
        </object>
    </childNodes>
    <someOtherNode/>
</parentNode>
```

How do I go about doing this? I've considered recursion (traversing the XML tree, anything that is named the same gets wrapped in a parent Node and change their names, etc.) which seemed to become complex quickly. I also considered XSLT but am maybe not familiar enough with this.

Comment: It is not clear which elements you need to wrap and which not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have understood the exact rules, it seems, once an element has child elements of the same name that are not `object` elements you want to `wrap` them and rename them to `object` and then do that recursively. In XSLT 2 or 3 (available for Java using Saxon 9 which is available in the open-source HE edition on Sourceforge and Maven) you can therefore group child elements with `for-each-group` on the `node-name()` and check there are at least two and they are not `object` elements, in that case you wrap them, then rename them, using different modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="wrapper-name" as="xs:QName" select="QName('', 'object')"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="wrap"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="wrap" priority="5">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#default"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] and current-grouping-key() ne $wrapper-name">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="rename"/>
                    </xsl:copy>                      
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="#default"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>      
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="rename">
        <xsl:element name="{$wrapper-name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#default"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[*]" mode="rename">
        <xsl:element name="{$wrapper-name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="wrap"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzQU